# KeyError: 'requestContext', FastAPI, Mangum, Serverless

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, fastapi

I am trying to use Serverless Framework to deploy a Python Fast API WebApp.
Is is related to issue:

https://github.com/jordaneremieff/mangum/issues/126

When I deploy it using serverless, sls depoy and Invoke the function I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'requestContext'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/mangum/adapter.py", line 110, in __call__
    return self.handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/mangum/adapter.py", line 130, in handler
    if "eventType" in event["requestContext"]:
```

I have tried with python 3.8 and 3.7.
Not able to find a resolution on the web for the same.
Also tried using the parameters spec_version=2(which is not required I feel).

I feel something is missing here, the issue is somewhere around:

```
Adapter requires the information in the event and request context to form the ASGI connection scope.
```

Wondering if anyone has got FastAPI working on AWS Lambda using serverless Framework.

My handler:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum


app = FastAPI()
handler = Mangum(app)

@app.get("/ping")
def ping():
    return {'response': 'pong'}
```

serverless.yml:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: dev
  region: ap-southeast-1
  memorySize: 256

functions:
  ping:
    handler: ping.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: ping
          method: get
          cors: true
```

My requirements.txt

```
appnope==0.1.0
backcall==0.2.0
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
decorator==4.4.2
fastapi==0.61.1
h11==0.9.0
httpcore==0.10.2
httptools==0.1.1
httpx==0.14.1
idna==2.10
ipython==7.17.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.17.2
mangum==0.9.2
parso==0.7.1
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
prompt-toolkit==3.0.6
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pydantic==1.6.1
Pygments==2.6.1
requests==2.24.0
rfc3986==1.4.0
six==1.15.0
sniffio==1.1.0
starlette==0.13.6
traitlets==4.3.3
typing-extensions==3.7.4.2
urllib3==1.25.10
uvicorn==0.11.8
uvloop==0.14.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
websockets==8.1
```

Comment: I had a similar issue running in AWS. I think the cause was that "Use Lambda Proxy integration" was not ticked on in API Gateway. I guess this meant that the event that Mangum expected was not being passed through.

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies within the `mangum` adapter expecting input similar to the `event` content specified by [AWS API Gateway shown here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html). You'll see that there's a `requestResponse` dictionary there that the Mangum adapter seems to strictly require to function. If your AWS Lambda event doesn't contain that key, then you'll need to add a placeholder field or construct a new context dictionary for it to look for.

This can be done by creating a custom handler [as shown within this part of the Mangum docs](https://mangum.io/adapter/). If you don't particularly care about what the adapter reads as the context then you can get a working version going with the following:

```
def handler(event, context):
    event['requestContext'] = {}  # Adds a dummy field; mangum will process this fine
    
    asgi_handler = Mangum(app)
    response = asgi_handler(event, context)

    return response
```

Comment: When I do this, I next get a `KeyError: 'multiValueQueryStringParameters'` in `site-packages/mangum/adapter.py` This is with Mangum 0.10.0. 

For background, I'm basically trying to invoke my lambda locally with `sls invoke local --function myApp`

Comment: Were you able to resolve this @JordanDimov ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide at least the **minimal** `Event data`, like in the example below,
when you invoke a FastAPI-based lambda function (for example via AWS console Lambda -> Test Event):

```
{
  "resource": "/",
  "path": "/api/v1/test/",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "requestContext": {
  },
  "multiValueQueryStringParameters": null
}
```

Please see details about the **Event format** in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event

The need comes from the `mangum` adapter for FastAPI, explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64403553/392118).